# Android - Viewpager doesn't display content

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment that hosts a ViewPager with 3 fragments, 2 of them contain ListView (not inherits FragmentList)

The problem is:

If I click on one of the items in one of the list the application navigates me correctly to a new fragment, but, if I press the back button and go back to the ViewPager, a can see a blank fragment, only the first fragment who didn't have ListView is created, none of the other fragments are displayed, nor even their onStart is called

What's wrong? I suppose the fragment is not attached again, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: please put your code here.